# Universal file protection for any doamin throug .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to dissallow access to pdf files for unregistred users.
And I know the way to do it through .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://sub.mydomain.com/module
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [L,F]
```

Only registred users can view http://sub.mydomain.com/module page

But I need such rule to fit any domain, something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://%{HTTP_HOST}/module
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [L,F]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove host part and check for `/module` URI as referrer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/module
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [L,F]
```

But keep in mind any check using `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is not very strong check as clients can spoof it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but can add a stronger check, if I REALLY need registred users could open PDF file in a browser window? Otherwise force file download could be an option, as newboyhun offered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using a back-end language, for example PHP.

Disallow access for your folder, not your files.

Then you can write a script in your preffered language to serve the pdf file to the registered user.